# Iptables не переадресует трафик с порта на порт

Tags: linux, сеть, iptables, snmp

Есть задача переадресовывать трафик из порта 162(по нему приходит внешний трафик snmp-trap) на порт 1062. Для того чтобы не запускать logstash под рутом. Трафик tcpdump вижу на порту 162. На 1062 не вижу(только с помощью telnet по порту), как я понимаю я его и не могу увидеть tcpdump'ом.
Настройки Iptables:

```
    $ sudo iptables -t nat -L
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DNAT       tcp  --  default              anywhere             tcp dpt:snmp-trap to:0.0.0.0:1062
DNAT       udp  --  default              anywhere             udp dpt:snmp-trap to:0.0.0.0:1062
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL
REDIRECT   tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:snmp-trap redir ports 1062
REDIRECT   udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:snmp-trap redir ports 1062
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             10.0.0.1        tcp dpt:snmp-trap to:10.0.0.2:1062
DNAT       udp  --  anywhere             10.0.0.1        udp dpt:snmp-trap to:10.0.0.2:1062
```

Как можно проверить есть ли переадресация по порту? Система : Linux 4.9.0-7-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.110-3+deb9u2 (2018-08-13) x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Удалил первые 2 правила и последние 2 правила, заработало.

Answer (score 0):

По идее, должно хватить одного
`iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p udp --dport 162 -j REDIRECT --to-port 1062`

Первые две строчки в вашей текущей конфигурации, мне кажется, вообще лишние.